# 12 volt DC to 12 volt AC sine wave inverters for 10 watt and 22 watt pumps

Tags: inverter, wave, sine

I have two 12 volt AC small water pumps that I want to run on 12 volt DC (solar). One pump is rated 6 watts (max ~10 watts) and the other pump is rated 16 watts (max ~22 watts). Since I need to convert DC to AC... and if remembering correctly it is best to be a sine wave output (not square wave) since the target is a motor.

Can someone please design two simple 12 volt DC to 12 volt AC sine wave inverters for the 10 watt and 22 watt pumps?

Would these devices output a lot of heat so as to require some method to extract the heat? (I want to pot the inverter in epoxy to make it waterproof.)

Comment: are these 50 or 60Hz AC motors?

Comment: @RonMauldin  Out of curiosity, could you post the links to the pumps?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and probably the cheapest way to go is to purchase an automotive 12 volt inverter to convert the 12 VDC to 120 VAC.  Then use a 120 VAC to 12 VAC power transformer to convert the inverter output to 12 VAC. The waveform out of most inverters is not sinusoidal although after going through the transformer its waveshape will probably improve since the transformer has limited bandwidth.  If you need a sine wave, you can purchase a higher quality inverter.